# Out Of Time variance test method and threshold for logistic regression models

Tags: regression, logistic, out-of-sample, f-statistic

I am interested in designing a test statistic for checking the out-of-time variance of a logistic regression model relative to the model development sample at an observation level. We did something similar for time series models based on the F-statistic which compares the error in the out-of-time predictions with development sample (below) and checking if a similar analogy can be expanded to the logistic regression models.

[image: F-statistic]

Can you please suggest if there is already some available resource that i can look into.

Thanks.